# Ruby indexer method

Tags: ruby, indexer

Is there in Ruby the concept of indexer method such as in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, a method named `[]` taking a single argument:

```
>> class Foo
>>  def [](idx)
>>   idx * 5
>>  end
>> end
=> nil
>> 
?> f = Foo.new
=> #<Foo:0x101098d80>
>> f[8]
=> 40
>> f[1]
=> 5
```

If you need to *set* a value at an index, name the method `[]=`.